# BootstrapToken forMSGraphAccess in Outlook

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins, office-js-helpers

I want to use SSO in Outlook to get the BookstrapToken with MSGrapAccess and I'm getting the error "13012". In the documentation says that this error is only possible while sideloading, but I also get it once I deploy the addin.

I'm not doing anything special:

```
bootstrapToken = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({ allowSignInPrompt: true, allowConsentPrompt: true, forMSGraphAccess: true });
```

This is the error I get:

```
{code: 13012, message: "API is not supported in this platform.", name: "API Not Supported"}
```

All the permissions are granted in Azure.

Is it possible to get the BootstrapToken foMSGraphAccess or I need to use a different sign in method?

Thank you

Comment: To be sure, which Outlook client are you using, and what is the version of that client? My understanding from [this part of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph#distributing-sso-enabled-add-ins-in-microsoft-appsource) is Outlook will always return this error when the forMSGraphAccess parameter is used unless the add-in is installed from AppSource.

Comment: This isn't clear from the documentation section I linked to, but I believe the token will still work for a side-loaded add-in that has admin consent so long as the forMSGraphAccess parameter is not used. You mentioned that "all the permissions are granted in Azure". Assuming the add-in is not already published to AppSource, could you try the API call again without the forMSGraphAccess parameter?

Comment: And if want to use the forMSGraphAcces parameter? I want to use MSGraph to get Teams messages. I already do it in PowerPoint with this same method, and I also want to do it in Outlook.

Comment: Can you confirm if the API works without the parameter? The parameter is supported once the add-in is published to AppSource (if you intend to publish it).

Comment: The API works without the parameter. And now I found the way to make it work with the parameter. The problem was that I was using allowConsentPrompt and forMSGraphAccess at the same time. Without allowConsentPrompt, I can use forMSGraphAccess with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to make it work with the parameter. The problem was that I was using `allowConsentPrompt` and `forMSGraphAccess` at the same time. Without `allowConsentPrompt`, I can use `forMSGraphAccess` with no problem.